Help identifying a resistor. It goes to a GearOne PA system
This goes to a GearOne 2400 Pa system. When I turn it on it omit a smell. Took it apart and turned it on and I saw a small bit of smoke coming from the white resistor. Any help would be great.Thanks
Chris

You'll need to post more information, such as a photograph, etc

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

why do you need to identify the resistor?

If you REALLY want the aswer, you need to include a picture of the board and the resistor in question.

Do you mean a resistor like this  ? https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=white+resistor#vhid=dKkVLFXYlUygEM&vssid=l

It is likely that something else has failed, causing the resistor to pass excessive current.  You will have to find and fix that other fault before replacing the resistor.

Sorry for no picture thought I had it posted. It is posted now.
